# iOS app Update on new MySQL entry

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I am trying to implement "passive-waiting" in an iOS app, connected to a MySQL database. The app needs to get information from the database, which is no problem, but what I can't figure out, is how i can get the MySQL database to somehow notify the app when a change occurs.

It could be implemented, by simple having the app constantly check the database asking for new entries, but that is not very efficient. Would be smarter if the app would only connect and ask the DB for data, when it KNOWS there is newly submitted data to fetch.

How can this be implemented?

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called "Push notifications". Here is one of the tutorials I've found with a quick search: https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications